# angular 1.5 Routing using $routeConfig vs $router.config

Tags: angularjs

I am working more with the new angular router.  Most of the posts I see are around 2.0 which should be very similar.

However,  I have been working through the source code  https://github.com/brandonroberts/angularjs-component-router/tree/master/lib.

I have noticed that there is use of $routerRootComponent.  I have been trying to figure out if this can be used as the default starting place with components.  However, I am getting an error

```
Error: Component "Root" has no route config.
```

I initially believed I was setting up the routeConfig correctly in the controller for the component like so ...

```
(function() {
    'use strict;'
    angular
        .module('componentTutorial.home')
        .value('$routerRootComponent', 'componentTutorial.home')
        .component('home',HomeComponentOptions);

        var HomeComponentOptions = {

            bindings: {  
                title: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: HomeController      
        }

        function HomeController ($router) {
            $routeConfig: [
                {path: '/home...', name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true}
            ];
        }
})();
```

My desire is to keep routes close to their home controller.  Initially I had set up a directive and hosted all of the routes in one directive's controller, but that can be confusing to set up child routes and difficult to find.

-Ex

```
unction AppController($router) {
        console.log('configuring routers');

        $router.config([
            {
                path: '/',
                component: 'home',
                name: 'Home'
            },
            {
                path: '/**',
                component: 'notFound',
                name: 'NotFound'
            },
            {
                path: '/about',
                component: 'about',
                name: 'About'
            }

        ]);
    }
```

Any insight into setting up the components with routes would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Where is it getting the component name "Root" from?

Comment: Old question that was never answered.  Some noticeable changes though since I asked this 2 months ago.    https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    'use strict;'
    angular
        .module('componentTutorial.home', ['ngComponentRouter'])
        .value('$routerRootComponent', 'app')
        .component('home',HomeComponentOptions);

        var HomeComponentOptions = {

            bindings: {  
                title: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: HomeController      
        }

        function HomeController ($router) {
            $routeConfig: [
                {path: '/home...', component: 'home', name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true}
            ];
        }
})();
```

Added 'ngComponentRouter' to the module dependencies. Changed the second param of value to an custom element that will be added inside the app(componentTutorial.home). See below for HTML example.
Thirdly add a new property component to the HomeController $routeConfig. The component value should be the components name.

HTML

```
 <app></app>
```